# Counting lineage in rows in a CSV from the end to beginning

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, biopython

Below I have a CSV file contains a lineage in every column. every column has a different length of lineage. I tried to make the counting from the end of the lineage as I am counting from the last elements towards the beginning of the lineage.

```
Column1             Column2             Column3
root                root                root
cellular organisms  cellular organisms  cellular organisms
Eukaryota           Eukaryota           Eukaryota
Sar                 Sar                 Viridiplantae
Alveolata           Alveolata          
Apicomplexa         Apicomplexa
Aconoidasida
```

I tried the below code by the amazing @xjcl but the problem is the script considers all lineage rows to be the same length and produces wrong values. Any help

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def filter_and_count(df, search_string):
    df_filtered = df.loc[:, (df == search_string).any(axis=0)] # to access a group of rows and columns by label
    return pd.melt(df_filtered)['value'].value_counts() # using more than one column as an identifire 
    
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/test.csv")  # read the csv file
df = df.transpose()
df = pd.melt(df[-2:])['value'].value_counts() #counting phyla

df.to_csv (r'/Users/Desktop/eukaryotes.csv') # the output file
```

The output I am looking for is to have the groups listed at the end to be at the top with their counts as below

```
group              count
Aconoidasida       1
Apicomplexa        2
Alveolata          2
Sar                2
Viridiplantae      1
Eukaryota          3
cellular organisms 3
root               3
```

Comment: Could you add a copyable or downloadable sample of your data, along with the expected output?

Comment: Hi @JanWilamowski I've done some modifications  to provide copyable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that each row contains the same category (e.g. order, family, species etc):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'Column1': ['root', 'cellular organisms', 'Eukaryota', 'Sar', 'Alveolata', 'Apicomplexa', 'Aconoidasida'],
'Column2': ['root', 'cellular organisms', 'Eukaryota', 'Sar', 'Alveolata', 'Apicomplexa', ''],
'Column3': ['root', 'cellular organisms', 'Eukaryota', 'Viridiplantae', '', '', '']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).replace('', np.nan)
```

gives

```
              Column1             Column2             Column3
0                root                root                root
1  cellular organisms  cellular organisms  cellular organisms
2           Eukaryota           Eukaryota           Eukaryota
3                 Sar                 Sar       Viridiplantae
4           Alveolata           Alveolata                 NaN
5         Apicomplexa         Apicomplexa                 NaN
6        Aconoidasida                 NaN                 NaN
```

You can loop over the rows and calculate their value counts as dictionaries, then merge them (note the reversal using `.loc[::-1]`):

```py
counts = df.apply(lambda row: row.value_counts().to_dict(), axis=1)
merged = {group: count for d in counts.loc[::-1] for group, count in d.items()}
```

gives

```
{'Aconoidasida': 1,
 'Alveolata': 2,
 'Apicomplexa': 2,
 'Eukaryota': 3,
 'Sar': 2,
 'Viridiplantae': 1,
 'cellular organisms': 3,
 'root': 3}
```

which you can convert to a DataFrame if you want:

```py
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(merged, orient='index', columns=['count'])
```

gives

```
                    count
Aconoidasida            1
Apicomplexa             2
Alveolata               2
Sar                     2
Viridiplantae           1
Eukaryota               3
cellular organisms      3
root                    3
```

Comment: Honestly, That's a very organized and clear answer, thanks. Can I ask how the code would be if I planned to count just the last 2 species that come before NaN in every column?

Comment: You could replace `df` with `df.apply(lambda col: col.dropna()[-2:], axis=0)`

Comment: is there a way to count the last but 1 element which is before NAN in every column?

Comment: everything except the last entry is `df.apply(lambda col: col.dropna()[:-1], axis=0)`. These is simple sequence indexing, I suggest you read up on that.